# Can we read html content of visited site from another application in rooted android device?

Tags: android, html, root, sandbox

I understand that sandboxing prevents one app coming across another app or its data at anytime. But in case of rooted device and providing all the permission, whatever is required, can an application read the html tags or contents of the webpage that is opened in chrome or other browser ?

To be more clear: I am seeking a way to look on the users web activity or application activity from the eye of operating system. Literally, it means i am looking for the highest level of access permission in rooted device.